# How to use Twilio Voicemail API

Tags: twilio, voicemail

I'm working on Twilio API to create a Voicemail option for my clients. What I want is record a voicemail if a number is out of reach or not picked up within given number of seconds lets say 10 seconds. I have created an XML like this. Default XML is given below if a dialed number is out of reach

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Response>
    <Dial action="1122.php?voicemail=1" timeout="10">
        <Number >111222333</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Then it will hit again 1122.php?voicemail=1 URL. Then XML will be

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Response>
 <Say>Please leave a message at the beep. Press the star key when finished.</Say>
  <Record action="http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=someemail@gmail.com" method="GET" maxLength="120" finishOnKey="*" />
</Response>
```

But it is not working properly.

What am I missing??? Please Help..

Comment: which bit is not working? The voicemail does not record or the email is not sent or nothing happens?